# Office 365 - How to refer and apply custom master page in sharepoint hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, custom-masterpage

I have a custom master page. I want this master page to be applied for an app(sharepoint hosted). The app contains an aspx page.

By default, the aspx inherits the master page as below:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
```

When I add reference to inherit Seattle.Master as below - the seattle.master is perfectly applied to the app :

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master" Language="C#" %>
```

Same way, if I apply my custom master page(below is the code), it doesnt work. The app throws error.

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/MyCustomMasterPage.master" Language="C#" %>
```

Note: The Seattle.Master and CustomMasterPage.Master are in the same location.

I want to know, how we can apply custom master page to our sharepoint hosted app in Office 365.

Please suggest

Thank You.

Comment: Why we can not use the existing master page? What is the purpose of module here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Creating Custom Master Page for Hosted Apps](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/817340/Creating-Custom-Master-Page-for-Hosted-Apps)

Create a Module in your project to add the master page that you just created above.

- Add your custom master page to this module.
- You will need to modify the elements.xml file so that your master page will go to the master page gallery of your app as below:

  `<File Path="ModuleName\CustomMasterPageName.master" 
      Url="_catalogs/masterpage/ CustomMasterPageName.master" 
      Type="GhostableInLibrary"></File>`
- Replace ModuleName with your module name.
- Replace CustomMasterPageName with your master page name.
- The above change will deploy the master page into the master page catalog document library of your app.
- GhostableInLibrary will make sure the document is placed within the document library.

Change the master page name for your App Pages as below:

`MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/ CustomMasterPageName.master"`

Comment: Thanks, This worked. I have another question. I have deployed the masterpage via sharepoint module through Visual Studio. Given the File Path :     <File Path="MasterPages\Test.master" Url="_catalogs/masterpage/Test.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" /> But I dont find the master page in my master page gallary. Any reasons why? Please help.

Comment: Simply, Your master page will be deployed in APP Web not in your Host Web.