# How to apply host web custom master page to SharePoint hosted app in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have created a SharePoint hosted app and deployed it to my Online site. But is there a method to apply host web custom master page to SharePoint hosted app.

Please solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

By default your SharePoint app will use **app.master** master page.

To apply custom master page, Please check this link: [Office 365 - How to refer and apply custom master page in sharepoint hosted app?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137558/office-365-how-to-refer-and-apply-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-hosted-app)

Comment: I have already used this method, But I want to inherit my host web master page to SharePoint hosted app. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: May be this link will help you :http://www.casvaniersel.com/2015/01/custom-masterpages-and-sharepoint-hosted-apps/